# Creating a counting variable that restarts at 1

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a variable that adds one to its previous value, then starts back at 1 when a different variable changes.

Right now, I'm trying to use shift and ifelse, to no avail:

```
example <- ifelse(CountryID == shift(CountryID,1), 1,
1+shift(CountryID,1))
```

I'm assuming this doesn't work because of the self-referential nature of the variable.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output for others to understand your problem better.

Comment: Are you counting frequency of CountryID?

Comment: I think the problem is not R but the way you are thinking your algorithm

Comment: Probably something like `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(CountryID) %>% mutate(Count = row_number())`

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways of looking at this, which I will demonstrate with the following sample data:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(v1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2),
                 v2 = c(6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 8, 1, 2, 9, 4, 6, 5))
```

The first is to assume that you want to restart any time there's a change in another variable, even if the value at the time of change has occurred earlier in the set.

If that's the case, you could consider the `rleid` function from "data.table". Observe how the counter variable gets reset even for previously occurring values in "v1":

```
DT[, N := sequence(.N), by = rleid(v1)][]
#     v1 v2 N
#  1:  1  6 1
#  2:  1  7 2
#  3:  2  5 1
#  4:  2  4 2
#  5:  2  6 3
#  6:  1  8 1
#  7:  1  1 2
#  8:  3  2 1
#  9:  3  9 2
# 10:  3  4 3
# 11:  1  6 1
# 12:  2  5 1
```

The second perspective would be to assume that you are looking for a cumulative count just grouped by another variable, whether the values are contiguous or not. Observe how the counter continues for the repeated values in "v1".

```
DT[, N := sequence(.N), by = v1][]
#     v1 v2 N
#  1:  1  6 1
#  2:  1  7 2
#  3:  2  5 1
#  4:  2  4 2
#  5:  2  6 3
#  6:  1  8 3
#  7:  1  1 4
#  8:  3  2 1
#  9:  3  9 2
# 10:  3  4 3
# 11:  1  6 5
# 12:  2  5 4
```