# Cumulative count in gamble simulation - Martingale

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate a [Martingale a gambling strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system)), in which the gambler double his bet after every loss, so that the first win would recover all previous losses plus win a profit equal to the original stake. The martingale strategy has been applied to roulette as well, as the probability of hitting either red or black is close to 50%.

So, I encounter a situation that  I need count the time I have lost or won.

For example, if a game result is

```
   result
   0
   1
   0
   1
   1
   0
   0
```

the bet and the money (if the beginning is 100)

```
   result bet money
   0 1 100
   1 2 101
   0 1 100
   1 2 102
   1 1 103
   0 1 102
   0 2 101
```

I actually need calculate how many time I am lost and winning as the following to calculate the bet I need.

```
   result count
   0 1
   1 1
   0 1
   1 1
   1 2
   0 1
   0 2
```

I found that ave could be done in similar situation when the result is not repeated.

Could anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand your last table. If `result` is a 0, you loose, if it is a 1 you win. Is the last table what you want to get?  What does `count` mean?

Comment: Should the `count`-variable restart everytime the `result`-variable changes its value?

Comment: yes, it is exactly as you said.

Comment: @ElongChen Take a look to `rle()` function, if you give it `result` column as input, it counts how many consecutive `0` or `1` do you have.

Comment: I found the following website works for my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449102/creating-a-counting-variable-that-restarts-at-1-in-r

Answer (score 0):

cumsum(result) should work to count winning results
and cumsum(1-result) for losses

Comment: I found the following syntax works     DT[, N := sequence(.N), by = rleid(id)][]