# Restart index for duplicate groups and sequence within group

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

`site` is my data, and I would like to derive `trip` and `seq`.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(site=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B"), 
                 trip=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5), 
                 seq =c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,1))
```

Comment: `trip` can be derived from [Increment by 1 for every change in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661269/increment-by-1-for-every-change-in-column) while `seq` can be derived from [Creating a counting variable that restarts at 1 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449102/creating-a-counting-variable-that-restarts-at-1-in-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment by 1 for every change in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661269/increment-by-1-for-every-change-in-column) and [Creating a counting variable that restarts at 1 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449102/creating-a-counting-variable-that-restarts-at-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rleid()`:

```
dt[,trip:=rleid(site)][,seq:=1:.N, "trip"]
```